# Screen reader stops reading aria-valuetext after it doesn't change for multiple steps at any point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am testing `Safari` screen reader on `OS X` and have an `input` of `type` `range`.

I am using `aria-valuemin`, `aria-valuemax`, `aria-valuenow`, and `aria-valuetext` to specify the screen reader output when the scale is moved.

However, if at any point the scale changes but the `aria-valuetext` does not, then all values thereafter are not read, even once the `aria-valuetext` starts changing again.

The value for `aria-valuetext` sometimes does not change for a few steps due to `Math.floor()` rounding.

Is this a problem with how I have specified the DOM attributes?

Here is a `react` [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-faraday-xl3x3) small reproducible example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        type="range"
        min="1"
        max="2"
        step="0.01"
        defaultValue="1"
        onChange={e => setScale(e.target.value)}
        aria-valuemin="1"
        aria-valuemax="2"
        aria-valuenow={scale}
        aria-valuetext={`${Math.floor(scale * 100)}%`}
       />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this case, some of the values of `112%` are rounded down and so cause the issue.

Comment: Never seen this before but my immediate thought is that when the same value is reported for a step up it breaks. The easiest way to try and solve it to not use `Math.floor` and instead use `parseFloat(scale * 100).toFixed(0)` to round to 0 significant figures. This should then match the `aria-valuenow` figure and scale correctly. Not sure if that fixes the problem (as I said never seen this) but worth a go?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie indeed, this does fix the problem - still curious to why it doesn't work in the first place. Must be a bug with Apple VoiceOver.

Comment: highly likely a bug, one interesting test would be to see if updating `aria-valuenow` but leaving `aria-valuetext` the same (updating it to the same value) causes the issue. I don't have a Mac to test. If that is the bug (and not updating to the same value) then that would be a good bug to report. Glad that sorted it anyway.